# Throttling KVO bindings (Xamarin / Mac )

Tags: c#, xcode, xamarin, interface-builder, xamarin.mac

I have a Mac desktop app in Xamarin.

There is a KVO Model that the UI is bound to using interface builder.

I also listen out for changes to the values in the model, and when changed, update attached hardware with the new value over a Serial Port connection.

The problem I have is with the Sliders.  The bound value on the slider updates on every step of the slider, rather than when the user releases the slider. This I want so I can update the text field showing the value, but I DON'T want it to trigger my handler until they release.

I can set the slider to `continuous = false`, which solves the handler issue, but then the textfield only updates on release.

I can't see anyway to configure the binding to trigger once the user *finishes* sliding, or a way to throttle the bound callback, so it only runs once within a given timeframe.

- Can you trigger the binding update once the user releases the mouse?
- Is there a way to throttle the callback?
- Would it be better practice to listen out for UI events to update the hardware? Rather than the bound model value changes?

Below is my current set up.....

[image]

**In the Settings Model**

```
[Register("SettingsModel")]
public class CameraSettingsModel : NSObject
{
    Export("GainMode")]
    public int GainMode { get; set; }
}
```

**Interface builder settings**

[image: Interface builder settings]

**In my view controller...**

Manually make the var holding the `Settings` model KVO compliant as well. (the `Settings` model gets swapped out for different models depending on user settings, so needs to trigger a WillChange etc for the bindings to refresh)

```
 private CameraSettingsModel _settings;
    [Export("Settings")]
    public CameraSettingsModel Settings
    {
        get 
        { 
            return _settings; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            WillChangeValue("Settings"); 
            _settings = value; 
            DidChangeValue("Settings"); 
        }
    }
```

Listen out for changes

```
   Settings.AddObserver("GainValue", NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, updateGainValue);
```

Update the hardware

```
   private void updateGainValue(NSObservedChange obj)
    {
        //update the hardware here
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you have to use an event instead of binding, because when you use a binding each time that the value changes, the binded property changes

Comment: @ganchito55 Yeah, but on mac there does not appear to be an appropriate event.  I could subclass the NSSliderCell as raise a custom event when the tracking has finished, but that wouldn't catch people using the keyboard!